# Load Tensorflow v1 model weights into a Tensorflow Core 2.0 alpha model (which is a tf.keras.Model)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a checkpoint that was created with tf.train.Saver(). I am currently updating my codebase to Tensorflow v2.0 that uses eager execution and I am trying to load this checkpoint into a tf.keras.Model.

```
    model = MyModel()
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

However, this throws the following error:

NotImplementedError: Streaming restore not supported from name-based checkpoints. File a feature request if this limitation bothers you.

I also tried to use CheckpointManager without much success.

```
    ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(net=model)
    manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, "path/to/checkpoint_dir", max_to_keep=3)
    ckpt.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
```

Is there a way to use TF v1 model weights in TF v2 ?

It is really time consuming to retrain models on ImageNet from scratch.

Comment: Is the v1 model you're loading from also a tf.keras.Model? If so, it's probably easier to save with tf.train.Checkpoint from v1 and load in v2 with a matching tf.train.Checkpoint. That way it doesn't matter if variable names change.

Comment: Unfortunately, the v1 model was not tf.keras.Model. What I ended up doing was to first load the model as a dict with tf.compat.v1 right into the graph that TF2 model was defined in. Then, manually did layer.set_weights for each network layer. This overall process is very hacky and painful. I really hope that Tensorflow will release guidelines about better way to do this as this will be a very widespread issue in the near future, as and when TF1 support gets discontinued. I am not listing this as an answer, as my approach was hacky.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem ? Needed for my eager convertion. @CodeEnthusiast

Comment: Yes, I manually did layer.set_weights for each network layer. There might be a better solution. This worked for me though.